# What is this Date Time Format? 2019-01-17T10:49:55-05:00

Tags: c#, datetime

As the question states, I'm trying to figure out what this datetime format is: `2019-01-17T10:49:55-05:00`. Through research, I've figured out up to this point: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` But the last few numbers, I have no idea what they represent. The only thing I came up with is milliseconds but that is usually 3 number after a decimal like this: `.fff` which does not fit this scenario.

Comment: Looks like the ISO 8601 format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.   The last section is how far from UTC/GMT it is.  In this case -5 hours.

To add a bit more, this is THE standard way to transfer date and times between systems.

Comment: how would you write that to parse it? What are the letters to represent it?

Comment: I wouldn't parse is manually.  It's built into `DateTime.Parse()`

Answer (score 2):

It is a date in ISO8601 format. The `-05:00` represents the UTC offset.

You can parse it using `DateTime.ParseExact` like so:

```
var ds = "2019-01-17T10:49:55-05:00";
var date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(ds, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an ISO 8601 timestamp with timezone information. The -05:00 means minus 5 hours.